# How to display a 'your payment is processing...' page to a user while processing the transaction in the background?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, payment-gateway, payment, resque

I run an online store that experiences very spiky traffic.  Recently, the entire system came to a standstill during a big sale event because the payment gateway had some kind of problem, and responses from their API took 17 seconds to respond instead of the normal 2-3 seconds.  There were hundreds of people attempting purchases simultaneously.  This caused all of the web worker threads in every web server in the production cluster to get tied up waiting for API responses from the payment gateway.  The entire production cluster was locked up and could not serve any page.

One solution to this problem would be to use Resque to process the payments in the background.  The web servers would immediately return a response to the user that would say something like, "Your payment is processing..."  The web server would be able to move on to the next web request.

The problem is continuing the checkout once the payment has been processed.  I can't use AJAX to poll for whether the transaction has completed, because many of the customers don't have JavaScript.  I can't depend on it.  I don't want to use JavaScript or any kind of server push technology with a low reliability rate because it would create an expensive customer support problem if a percentage of checkouts were to become stalled on the 'processing...' page.

How can I engineer the page flow so that the transactions can be processed in the background, reliably?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into an event-based solution (EventMachine, for example) and have it handle these requests.  The standard RoR servers will all crumble in this scenario.  Some sort of backend processing with javascript is definitely the easiest way to solve this, but if that's not an option, I'd explore moving that flow into something that's better designed to handle things like APIs not responding forever.

Comment: Thank you for your input.  Even if I were to switch the web framework out for something that could handle an infinite number of concurrent connections, I would still have a problem with some requests timing out when the payment gateway takes an unusually long time to respond.  I already have Resque running on the production server.  The only part that I can't figure out is how to set up the page flow, so that the 'processing...' page eventually transitions to a 'complete' or a 'declined' page.  Perhaps JavaScript and then a fallback to a meta refresh tag for when JavaScript doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try Gearman?

http://gearman.org/

Comment: Thanks!  I'm using Resque, which is a very similar system for background jobs.

https://github.com/defunkt/resque

Answer (score 0):

I know you said you can't rely on clients having Javascript enabled, but I don't believe it's elegant to try and achieve this without client-side scripting.

1. You could, for example, force your user to keeping clicking a refresh button to generate an HTTP request to pull back the status of the payment transaction from the server (either "processing", "succeeded" or "failed") until it's completed, but it's clunky.
2. Or, for a slightly better experience use a meta refresh instruction to automate the refresh, but it still makes your site look old-fashioned:

   <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2; url=http://site.com/checkout/?session=123" />
3. But my strong preference would be to USE client-side behaviour instead. Use it to immediately change the display. Use an AJAX library of your choice, JQuery or just Javascript. Manipulate the DOM to show just a "processing" messsage. OR, if you leave the existing page elements there, ensure every button or other submittable part of the form is disabled to prevent double-clicks by the user. AND warn the user that the payment make take several seconds. When the payment is processed the HTTP response will arrive to progress the screen, either to show there was a payment failure or success.

All these approaches should negate your worries about the time taken by the payment server to process the transaction. If there is a problem on your server side then it's a different problem to be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Respond with an "in process, we'll send you an email confirmation."  Have the background process send an email with a link as well as mark a record that indicates the result.  Then the customer can check back, or wait for the email and check back.

Anything you do with AJAX will tie-up the server answering the AJAX request.  Same problem.  Unless the request is simply polling for the result at some "low enough but not too low" frequency.  Polling is uglier than notification.